# How to return Data from call back of Graph API

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am Trying to implement signing up with Facebook feature for my react-native app and i am stuck at this stage that Data is successfully retrieved from the profile and I have check it on the alert screen. Here is my Code in which I call the Function of another component (FBLogin).First of all there is a Touchable Opacity(Custom UI for facebook login Button)

```
<TouchableOpacity  // This is in the Main Screen
          onPress={() => {
                this.goFacbookLogin()
              }}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Here is My Function which is being called on the onPress Event.

```
async goFacbookLogin(){ // This is also a function on the Main Screen

await FBLogin.facebookLogin().then((data) =>{
  alert("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

}

Now The FBLogin is basically a service for login as facebook. and it has a function facbookLogin()

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import {LoginManager, LoginButton, 
AccessToken,GraphRequest,GraphRequestManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk';


class FBLoginButton extends Component{// This is Implemented in another File 
 constructor(props) 
 {
  super(props);
  this.state = 
  {
    //screenWidth: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    //screenHeight: Dimensions.get("window").height,
    UserProfileInformation: 
    {
      UserAge: null,
      Gender: null,
      UserLocation: null,
      ImageUrl: null,
    }
   }
  }


async facebookLogin() 
{
  let _result;
  try 
  { 
    LoginManager.setLoginBehavior('NATIVE_ONLY');  
    _result = await LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 
    "email","user_birthday", "user_gender","user_hometown"]);
    console.warn("Done");
  } 
  catch (nativeError) 
  {
   try 
   {
       LoginManager.setLoginBehavior('WEB_ONLY');
    _result = await LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 
   "email", "user_birthday", "user_gender", "user_hometown"]);
   } 
   catch (webError) 
   {
     alert("Function Called Web Error");
   }
  }

 if (_result.isCancelled) 
 {
   alert('Login Cancel')
 } 
 else 
 {
     global.res1 = "None";
     const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
     const infoRequest = new GraphRequest
     (
       '/me',
       {
         accessToken: data.accessToken,
         parameters: 
         {
           fields: 
           {
            string: 'first_name, name, gender, birthday, email, hometown'
           }
         }
       },
       (error, result) => {
       if (error) 
       {
         alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
       } 
      else 
       {
         let UserProfileInformation = this.state.UserProfileInformation;  
         UserProfileInformation['Gender'] = result.gender;
         UserProfileInformation['UserLocation'] = result.hometown.name;
         this.setState({ UserProfileInformation: UserProfileInformation}, () 
        => console.warn("DDDDD: " + this.state.UserProfileInformation));
         res1 = result;
       }
     }
   );
    new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start()
    return(this.state.UserProfileInformation);
  }
  //return "Done";
  }
 }
 export default FBLogin = new FBLoginButton();
```

Now the Problem Here is that when Graph Request Starts the InfoRequest it Fetches the Data successfully in the callback function but i have no idea how to return it to the main function call in which i have implemented then statement after the function call. Currently The data gets stored in a state but as state takes time to change the return statement executed early and i got null but when i press the opacity button second time, the data is correct as it's previous state was changed.
i have tried global and let variables but they got destroyed after the callback function ends.

In Short All I want is to return this result to the facebookLogin in the Main Screen.

i am New in React Native so If any one can help it would really be appreciated.

Comment: Actually the Problem is all related to async and await kind of things as last statement is return statement from the function so the program runs the graph request in the background and returns the NULL object (state) which is not set yet.